# Diagonalizability of a Linear Map

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Please could somebody verify this:
$T$ is diagonalizable $\iff$ there exists a basis of $V$ (the vector space ) consisting of eigenvectors of $T$ 
$\iff$ the algebraic multiplicity of each eigenvalue is equal to its geometric multiplicity. If even one geometric multiplicity is strictly less than its corresponding algebraic multiplicity then there is no way the geometric multiplicities can all add up to $dim V $ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, this is **true.** Here's why: $T$ diagonalizable means that it has a diagonal representation with respect to some basis for $V$. If we have a basis of eigenvectors of $T$, then we know that the operator $T$ simply scales every basis vector of the space.

Knowing how matrices record the action of an operator, this gives us the following matrix representation for $T$:
$$ \mathcal{M}(T)=\begin{pmatrix}
    \lambda_1       &  &  &0 \\
       & \lambda_2 &   \\
       &  &  \ddots\\ 
0&&&\lambda_k 
\end{pmatrix}.$$
So, the equivalence of the first two statements should now be obvious (hopefully). If algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is equal to its geometric multiplicity, this means that there are $dimE(\lambda,T)$ linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to each eigenvalue $\lambda$, which means that indeed a basis of eigenvectors for the space exists.

This follows from
$$V=E(\lambda_1,T)\oplus\cdots\oplus E(\lambda_k,T)$$ 
if and only if $T$ diagonalizable.